Is having a circle in the relationships bad? (though not a circular per se)
Distributors have branches, branches have warehouses. Distributors have employees that may or may not belong to a warehouse (thus belonging to a branch). Employees are not necessarily belong just to distributors therefore I have a separation of employees from distributors via a junction table.
Here is the design I came up with:

I know I don't have a circular relationship, but the circle itself bothers me a bit. Is it ok to be able to go to warehouse_employees both via branches -> warehouses and via distributor_employees?
It might be opinionated, but is there a "better" design for this? I have another version where warehouse_employees is not there and distributor_employees is a ternary junction table between employees, distributor, and warehouses. I'm not sure if this is better, but the same concern remains.

I don't grok the specific data model, but there is nothing wrong with a circular dependency as such. Try to picture in which order data will get added and if that will cause a problem.

I also don't see anything wrong with that data model.
